# What's going on if someone don't pass many review tests?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

I usually pass the review tests. (In fact I can't remember the last time I failed.) But I wonder what's going on to someone who repeatedly fails to pass these tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one fails too many reviews (in a relative sense) then one will be banned from reviewing for some time. Failing them only rarely is inconsequential, and it is generally acknowledges that even a careful reviewer can fail some (due to such decisions sometimes being inherently subjective).

For some more details you can see the respective FAQ on MSE [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)
I believe the precise thresholds are not documented though.